# error on easy_install cpp-coveralls

Tags: ios, travis-ci, coveralls

It happens to me that most of the builds are compiled correctly, but from time to time the same error appears (without changing any .travis.yml parameter)

The error is:

**The command "sudo easy_install cpp-coveralls" failed and exited with 1 during .**

Now my build got stucked on it when the previous builds have successfully passed this step without problems.

- **This is the failing build**: https://travis-ci.org/pubnative/pubnative-ios-library/builds/49482893
- **This is the repo**: https://travis-ci.org/pubnative/pubnative-ios-library/

Why is it so randomly failing?

Answer (score 0):

try `` pip install cpp-coveralls --user `whoami` ``

edit:

- `pip install cpp-coveralls` is the way to install package on python (instead of easy_install)
- `` --user `whoami` `` is to install it without sudo, in a Travis container (like OP is doing)

Comment: Please explain what this does, and why OP should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through this yesterday. I've attached a simplified version of the [.travis.yml file](https://github.com/aero-ff/aero/blob/master/.travis.yml) I use for my project.

```
before_install:
  - pip install --user cpp-coveralls

after_success:
  - '$([ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ] && echo ~/Library/Python/2.7 || echo ~/.local)/bin/cpp-coveralls --gcov-options "\-lp"'
```

---

```
pip install cpp-coveralls --user
```

is indeed the correct way to do it, but where it ends up required a bit (a lot?) of research. The answer was simple, but incredibly un-documented.

Comment: I agree with you, It required a lot of research in order to make this work. It worked at the end.